# Url unshortner python and urilib Request

Tags: python, httpconnection

Im traying to unshort a few urls that have been shortened. For such thing I'm using https://pypi.org/project/fake-headers/ to create the headers

but i cant get it to work I get 400 and 406 status codes.

```
        url = 'http://   bit.ly   /377n4o6' #i had to add spaces end url is https://es.banggood.com/Xiaomi-Mi-A1-MiA1-Dual-Rear-Camera-5_5-inch-4GB-RAM-64GB-Snapdragon-625-Octa-core-4G-Smartphone-p-1196064.html      
        parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
        if parsed.scheme == '':
            url = 'http://' + url
            parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
        h = http.client.HTTPConnection(parsed.netloc, timeout=5)
        path = quote(parsed.path, safe='')

        header = Headers(
            browser="chrome",  # Generate only Chrome UA
            os="win",  # Generate ony Windows platform
            headers=True  # generate misc headers
            )
        #request is asking to have a parans, so I got one from another code.
        params = urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'})

        h.request('HEAD', path,params, header.generate())
        response = h.getresponse()
        print(response.status)
```

what could be wrong with this that fails?

thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to make your code a complete executable example - we should be able to paste your code into a file and run it, without having to work out what to add. Put yourself in the position of the people reading your question - and if you want those people to help they need you to make it easy to check out your code.

Comment: This is basically a complete executable example, what is missing? Aside from imports, you can pull this into an interpreter with barely any changes and it would run.